# AutoBeanFactory not working in GWT 2.3

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT 2.3.0. I tried to incorporate AutoBean functionality but it Shows me Exception

12:17:20.501 [ERROR] [webmaths] Uncaught exception escaped

caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBeanFactory
    at com.kuchnaya.maths.client.HtmlPlayer$6.onValueChange(HtmlPlayer.java:360)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.kuchnaya.maths.client.HtmlPlayer.onModuleLoad(HtmlPlayer.java:260)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl$16.onSuccess(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsyncWithoutCodeSplitting(GWT.java:312)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsync(GWT.java:256)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl.launchEntryPoint(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl.onModuleLoad(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntrypointDispatcher.onModuleLoad(EntrypointDispatcher.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanFactory
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1054)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.kuchnaya.maths.client.HtmlPlayer$6.onValueChange(HtmlPlayer.java:360)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.kuchnaya.maths.client.HtmlPlayer.onModuleLoad(HtmlPlayer.java:260)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl$16.onSuccess(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsyncWithoutCodeSplitting(GWT.java:312)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsync(GWT.java:256)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl.launchEntryPoint(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntryPointFactoryImpl.onModuleLoad(EntryPointFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.gwtmultipage.client.EntrypointDispatcher.onModuleLoad(EntrypointDispatcher.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 12):

You have to add

```
<inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.autobean.AutoBean" />
```

to your module.gwt.xml file to instruct the compiler to include the AutoBean files.